# Kinetic energy of electrons

Tags: energy, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Electrons are in orbit around the nucleus. I have two questions about this:

1. Where does the energy for them to orbit come from?
2. Is chemical energy another word the kinetic energy of these electrons?

Answer (score 3):

> "Electrons are in orbit around the nucleus."

The picture of electrons literally "orbiting" (e.g., moving around the nucleus like the moon orbits the earth) is the wrong way to think about the situation.

Electrons are often described as being in "orbitals" in quantum mechanics. This does not mean that the elections are "orbiting" in the classical sense. The quantum mechanical "orbitals" are typically stationary states of the Hamiltonian. The time dependence of observables like position and momentum is trivially constant (they don't change at all).

> Where does the energy for them to orbit come from?

From the interaction between the nucleus and the electron.

> Is chemical energy another word the kinetic energy of these electrons?

No, the kinetic energy is just $p^2/2m$. The "chemical energy" might include the kinetic energy in whole or in part depending on the exact meaning of "chemical energy."